# putting text in center of image with overpic

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, overpic

I would like to put some text at the center of a non-square image using (ideally) overpic. I tried:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{overpic}[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}
        \put(50,50){\makebox[0pt]{text}}
    \end{overpic}
\end{figure}
```

However, this only centers "text" in the horizontal direction. In the vertical direction the text is placed slightly above the center as the units are normalized normalized by whichever side is longer (in this case the width). Is there a way to \put some text in the actual center without manually inputting the image height?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a savebox to measure the size of the image.  Note that `\huge` comes before `\strutbox` which is font size dependent.  Also, `\dp\tempbox=0pt` and can be ignored.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}
Test above.

\begin{figure}[ht]
\savebox\tempbox{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\centering
  \usebox\tempbox
  \llap{\huge\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\ht\tempbox-0.5\ht\strutbox+0.5\dp\strutbox}%
    {\makebox[\wd\tempbox]{\textcolor{red}{text}}}}
\end{figure}

Text below.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without overpic:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
{\centering
\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image.png}}\Huge\bfseries\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\makebox[0pt]{\color{yellow}text}}\par}
\end{document}
```